# Json callback problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get a greasemonkey's script to work jquery and json.
this is the json url
http://www.sora101.net/auction.php?id=1&callback=

this is part of the script

```
$.getJSON("http://sora101.net/auction.php?id=1&callback=?",
                    function(data){
                        alert(data.id);
                    }
                    );
```

i always get something like this "`Error: jsonp1282646809490 is not defined`" in the console.

i also found this h**p://www.xucia.com/CrossSafe/test.html
on this site i get the right object returned but when i include this in my script it doesn't work...

can anyone help me? thanks and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should be using JSONP and now JSON as you're using different domains.

From jQyuery.getJSON() documentation:
Blockquote

> 

JSONP If the URL includes the string
  "callback=?" in the URL, the request
  is treated as JSONP instead. See the
  discussion of the jsonp data type in
  $.ajax() for more details.